# Classic ASP RegExp small change

Tags: html, regex, asp-classic

I have some regular expression code that grabs the data between the title tags on a page:

```
<%
    Function UrlExists(sURL)
        Dim objXMLHTTP
        Dim thePage
        Dim strPTitle   
        Dim blnReturnVal
        Dim objRegExp
        Dim strTitleResponse

        'Create object
        Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        on error resume next

        'Get the head
        objXMLHTTP.Open "HEAD", sURL, false
        objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
        objXMLHTTP.Send ""

        '404?        
        If Err.Number <> 0 or objXMLHTTP.status <> 200 then blnReturnVal = "0|404 Error" Else blnReturnVal = "1|"
        objXMLHTTP.close

        'If not 404
        if left(blnReturnVal,1) = "1" then

            'Get the physical page
            objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, false
            objXMLHTTP.Send ""
                thePage = objXMLHTTP.responseText 
                thePage = replace(thePage, vbCrlf, "")
            objXMLHTTP.close

            'Find title
            Set objRegExp = New Regexp

            objRegExp.IgnoreCase = true
            objregexp.Multiline = true
            objRegExp.Global = false
            objRegExp.Pattern = "<title[^>]*?>(.*)</title>" 

            set strPTitle =  objRegExp.Execute(thePage)
            strTitleResponse = strPTitle.Item(0).Value
            strTitleResponse = replace(strTitleResponse, vbCrlf, "")
            strTitleResponse = trim(strTitleResponse)
            if len(strTitleResponse) <1 OR strTitleResponse = "" then strTitleResponse = "(No Title)"

            set objRegExp = nothing
            strTitleResponse = replace(strTitleResponse,"</title>","")
            strTitleResponse = replace(strTitleResponse,"<title>","")
            strTitleResponse = replace(strTitleResponse,"'","&#39; ")
            blnReturnVal = blnReturnVal & strTitleResponse

        end if

        Set objXMLHTTP = nothing

        UrlExists = blnReturnVal
    End Function
%>
```

This works fine and has been for many months, but when I wrote it (stupidly?) I made the assumption each page would only have one or no title tags.  It's recently started to throw weird errors on the [John Lewis page](http://www.johnlewis.com/) because it has two titles in it's HTML:

```
    <title>John Lewis - Shop online at Britain's Favourite Retailer</title>
... bunch of html
<title>

    </title>
```

How can I modify the regexp to match only the first matched pair, not getting confused with the HTML above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In before all this "you should use a parser": make you regexp [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy):

```
objRegExp.Pattern = "<title[^>]*?>(.*?)</title>"
```

Notice the added `?` after `.*`. Per default `.*` will match *as much as possible*. This behaviour is inverted with the additional `?`, now matching *as little as possible*.

**Warning**: I know absolutely nothing about regular expressions i classic ASP (or "modern" ASP, if there is such a thing), but since the non-greedy / laziness operator is already used on the `<title>` tag match, I reckon it will work.